# Sound File not playing in pygame

Tags: python, audio, pygame, ubuntu-12.04, windows-7-x64

I'm having a lot of trouble getting a sound to play off of pygame.

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()

sounda = pygame.mixer.Sound('G:/Portable Python/asharp.ogg') #Path and Sound File
soundb = pygame.mixer.Sound('asharp.ogg') #This also slips through without prompting an error, presumably both cmds work


sounda.play()
soundb.play()
```

This is the code I've been playing around with and I cannot get the sound file to work on Portable python which is running 2.7.5 on my Windows 7 64bit desktop. I also tried this on my Linux laptop and when the sound-file is played I just hear a blip and not the actual sound file.

Anyone have any ideas?

**edit** I wanted to mention something about the soundfiles. Basically I created a synth using an ableton plugin 'vanguard'. Then what I did was export a note on that synth separately into .wav files. Then to get them into the .ogg format I used Audacity to cut the extra space on these notes and then export them out of Audacity into the .ogg format. Also when I created the .wav files I played them at a 70bpm. I'm not sure if that has anything to do with the output I'm getting in python. I need to finish up some homework and I'll try out other .ogg sound files if I can.

Comment: Out of curiosity is the volume turned up on your window's computer and not muted?

Comment: ahaha, yes it is turned up.  

This is what the shell outputs when I do sounda.play() <Channel object at 0x004F3210>

Comment: Have you tried adding channels in order to play this sound? Also have you made sure that the `.ogg` file will play correctly outside of the python application?

Comment: Yes the .ogg file does play on rythym box for ubuntu 12.04 and it runs on VLC on my windows computer. Any instruction on how to add channels to play the sound?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so for channels this is how you would essentially set it up. Please be aware that on each channel you may only post one sound at a time and trying to do more will result in the first stopping. You can however create multiple channels to play sound from.

More information can be found at:  http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html#pygame.mixer.Channel

```
channelA = pygame.mixer.Channel(1)
sounda = pygame.mixer.Sound("asharp.ogg")
channelA.set_volume(1.0)
channelA.play(sounda)
```

Answer (score 0):

sounda.play() returns an object which is necessary for playing the sound. With it you can also find out if the sound is still playing:

```
channela = sounda.play()
while channela.get_busy():
   pygame.time.delay(100)
```

And the same for soundb...